# Advise needed for multiple signin methods in a web application

Tags: authentication, oauth, single-sign-on

I'm looking for some strategic advise on the implementation of an application that supports multiple signin methods.

In fact I already have most of it working. In my application, I allow users to sign up and sign in using the classic approach: an account managed by me, where I offer all the user management features, such as sign in, sign out, sign up, email activation, password reset, password change, edit email address, etc.

However, users can also sign up and sign in using their Twitter account. The system will let the user authenticate at Twitter and authorize my application access to their account, then Twitter redirects to my application and I am given the Twitter user name. Currently, if that user name is not known to me, I create it in my database. If it is known to me, yet it is a different account type (a native account), I throw an error.

Basically, currently users have to choose a signin method at account creation and stick to it. There are two ways I can see to improve the situation:

**Allow for multiple signin methods**

Users would have one account, but multiple ways of signin in. Let's say a user has a native account named "joedirt", associated with email address "joe@dirt.com". Next, this user does not sign in using the native method, yet chooses the Twitter way. At Twitter he is called "joedirt" as well.

The problem here is that from Twitter I only get his username. It would be a major security leak if by name matching alone I could sign in to a native account.

What am I to do here? Ask the user that signs in with an additional method for his email address? It would be the only way to be sure that this concerns the same user, right?

**Allow for one signin method only, yet the ability to choose one at any time**

An alternative approach could be to let the user only use one signin method at a time, yet the option to set this as a preference and change it even after the account is created. Two scenarios could unfold:

- From native signin method to 3rd party signin method. Since I cannot get the email address from the 3rd party signin, how will I ever link the native account to a 3rd party account? Again, username matching is too weak, right?
- From 3rd party signin method to the native method. An unlikely event, should I even support this?

Sorry for the long story. I'm having a bit of a mental block on what the best approach is and what the consequences for each scenario are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about letting the user "link" her account to other sign-in methods when she is already signed in? That way, it wouldn't be a problem if the third-party provider only supplies limited information (such as the Twitter username).

Either way, I suggest you generate an unique native ID for each user instead of throwing errors when native usernames collide with third-party dito. Think of the user and her sign-in methods as different (but related) concepts.

Comment: Thanks, I was in so deep that I needed a clear, simple answer like that. I think it makes perfect sense to allow linkage of additional accounts when signed in. It's secure, allows for name variations across the providers and not that hard to implement.